# How to get list of apps in android that can be disabled or enabled programatically

Tags: android

I believe that all apps in android cannot be disabled. I would like to get list of all apps(i.e including System apps and Installed apps) that can be disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research..

I have found following code retrieves  list of System Apps in android. System apps are the apps that can be disabled or enabled.

```
    packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    // Flags: See below
    int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA | 
            PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |     
            PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;

    List<ApplicationInfo> applications = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flags);
    if((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            //System App
    }
```

Comment: why not just use `List<ApplicationInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.MATCH_SYSTEM_ONLY);` ?

Comment: `PackageManager.MATCH_SYSTEM_ONLY` requires Build.VERSION_CODES.N -- which didn't exist 3 years ago :-D